# Angular Waiting for Observable to complete before running function

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have looked at other similar questions but they seem old or confusing to me. Simply put I have an observable that calls an api which populates a list. I need to wait for the list to be populated so I can scroll down to a selected item in this list. The code keeps throwing a console error because the virtualScrollViewport is not actually available when it tries to run.

```
@ViewChild("virtualScroll", { static: true })
  public virtualScrollViewport: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

this.catalogueService.getAllCatalogues().subscribe((catalogueTitles) => {
          this.catalogueTitles = catalogueTitles;
          let selectedIndex = this.catalogueTitles.findIndex(item => item.companyId == newlyAddedItemId)
          this.virtualScrollViewport.scrollToIndex(selectedIndex) // causing error because it runs before the this.catalogueTitles has loaded the data
 });
```

How do I know that the subscription has complete so I can then run the scrollToIndex function?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess where `this.virtualScrollViewport` comes from? Without that information, the best we can say is make sure the variable is defined before fetching the observable.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I should have shown the @ViewChild part. I will edit...

Comment: Do your work in `AfterViewInit`, so you know the view has been instantiated. If `this.virtualScrollViewport` is still undefined, you probably have the targeted element in an `ngIf*` that evaluates false.

Comment: Thanks, yes I do have it in an *ngIf and it evaluates to false until the this.catalogueTitles has data back from the api.

Comment: sounds like you have a race condition between angular change detection cycle that's evaluating the `ngIf`, and you trying to use the element before it exits.

if you remove the ngIf does it solve the issue ?. also where exactly are you subscribing ?

Comment: If I remove the ngIf it finds the element but I need it to scroll to an item that appears in the list after it has come back from the api. I am adding a new item, saving it to the database, then repopulating the list, and then trying to scroll to that new item in the new list.

Comment: Pipe the observable into a `tap` operator and set the `this.catalogueTitles` before you hit the subscribe.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, the this.catologueTitles contains the object returned from the api. I need the refreshed data to set it.

Comment: `this.catalogueService.getAllCatalogues().pipe(tap(data => this.myVar = data)).subscribe`...

Comment: Great!, Thanks for your time on this, I did not know that piping the data with tap would also get the data from the api, now I can do what I need to in the subscribe and it will only do it once it has received the data..